# How do I create a delete button on every row in slickgrid with confirmation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

As the title said it, how do I do it?, I am using this button created by jiri:

[How do i create a delete button on every row using the SlickGrid plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784400/how-do-I-create-a-delete-button-on-every-row-using-the-slickgrid-plugin?answertab=votes#tab-top)

when I add an if(confirmation(msg)) inside the function it repeats me the msg ALOT 
maybe its because i refresh-ajax the table with each modification.

ask me if you need more info, I am still noob here in stackoverflow :P
(also if there is someway to "kill" the function)

here is the button, iam using(link) i added the idBorrada to check whetever the id was already deleted and dont try to delete it twice, also here is a confirm, but when i touch cancel it asks me again.

`$('.del').live('click', function(){
      var me = $(this), id = me.attr('id');
      //assuming you have used a dataView to create your grid
      //also assuming that its variable name is called 'dataView'
      //use the following code to get the item to be deleted from it
      if(idBorrada != id && confirm("¿Seguro desea eleminarlo?")){
          dataView.deleteItem(id);
          Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"${url}","c":"${gridId}","ep":{'borrar':JSON.stringify(id, null, 2)}});
      //This is possible because in the formatter we have assigned the row id itself as the button id;
      //now assuming your grid is called 'grid'
          //TODO
          grid.invalidate();
          idBorrada= id;
      }
      else{
      };
  });`

and i call the entire function again.
hope that help, sorry for the grammar its not my native language

Comment: In order for us to help you we're really going to have to see the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Since you say you are new, Please read [Jon Skeet's Check List](http://tinyurl.com/so-list) on posting a good question.

Comment: ok i must train how to post code :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps,

1. Add a delete link for each row with of the columns object as follows,

```js
var columns = 
   { id: "Type", name: "Application Type", field: "ApplicationType", width: 100, cssClass: "cell-title", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, validator: requiredFieldValidator, sortable: true },
   { id: "delete", name: "Action", width: 40, cssClass: "cell-title", formatter: Slick.Formatters.Link }
];
```

2. Add a Link Formatter inside slick.formatters.js as follows,

```js
"Formatters": {
   "PercentComplete": PercentCompleteFormatter,
   "YesNo": YesNoFormatter,
   "Link": LinkFormatter
}

function LinkFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
   return "<a style='color:#4996D0; text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer' onclick='DeleteData(" + dataContext.Id + ", " + row + ")'>Delete</a>";
}
```

3. Add the following delete function in javascript

```js
function DeleteData(id, rowId) {
   var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to permenantly delete this record!");
   if (result == true) {
       if (id) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "DeleteURL",
               data: { id: id },
               dataType: "text",
               success: function () {
               },
               error: function () {
               }
           });
       }
       dataView.deleteItem(id);
       dataView.refresh();}
}
```